# How to have a multi line statement in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an include statement with lots of variables being passed in.
Was wondering if there was any way to make it multiline.

Ex:
`{% include 'foo.html' with img_src='bar.jpg' img_text='baz' %}`

into
 `{% include 'foo.html' with 
img_src='bar.jpg' 
img_text='baz' %}`.

Comment: It was intentionally designed to keep it in a single line to keep tags simple

Comment: keep this kind of logic in the view or the template you are including....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/13i1dvy/comment/jk7uzyd/) on reddit that worked for me:

> This absolutely is possible, you just need to override Django's default regex to allow newlines. It's one of the first things I add to any project - I usually add it as `monkey.py` in the root of my project for clarity then import it from the `__init__.py`, but you could put it directly in `__init__.py` if you prefer:
>
> ```py
> import re
> from django.template import base as template_base
>
> # Add support for multi-line template tags
> template_base.tag_re = re.compile(template_base.tag_re.pattern, re.DOTALL)
> ```
>
> Not sure why that's not Django's default.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but you can not do that. The idea is to obtain the template as clean as possible.

If the problem is just a visual problem, you can not do that. If the problem is that the code grows and is difficult to maintain and is not verbose, may be necessary to rethink the variables.

In the view you can implement `get_context_data` and send an dict with the `src` and `text`. You get now only one variable.